# Parsing HTML in python3, re, html.parser, or something else?

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

I'm trying to get a list of craigslist states and their associates urls. Don't worry, I have no intentions of spaming, if you're wondering what this is for see the * below.

What I'm trying to extract begins the line after 'us states' and is the next 50 < li >'s. I read through html.parser's docs and it seemed too low level for this, more aimed at making a dom parser or syntax highlighting/formatting in an ide as opposed to searching which makes me think my best bet is using re's. I would like to keep myself contained to what's in the standard library just for the sake of learning. I'm not asking for help writing a regular expression, I'll figure that out on my own, just making sure there's not a better way to do this before spending the time on that.

*This is my first program or anything beyond simple python scripts. I'm making a c++ program to manage my posts and remind me when they've expired in case I want to repost them, and a python script to download a list of all of the US states and cities/areas in order to populate a combobox in the gui. I really don't need it, but I'm aiming to make this 'production ready'/feature complete both as a learning exercise and to create a portfolio to possibly get a job. I don't know if I'll make the program publicly available or not, there's obvious potential for misuse and is probably against their ToS anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lxml.html`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html). It's the best python html parser. It supports xpath!

Comment: Is this better than the xml.etree module Senthil Kumaran is recommending? edit: Oh wait, this isn't a builtin, I was trying to limit myself to the built ins as an exercise.

Comment: @kryptobs2000: There's no good html parser in the standard library. `xml.etree.ElementTree` and friends are **XML** parsers, not html parsers.

Comment: Yup, so I've come to find out. Giving lxml.html a try now, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is [xml.etree](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) an XML Parser available in the Python Standard library itself. You should not using regex for parsing XMLs. Go the particular node where you find the information and extract the links from that.

Comment: Is xml.etree a better option than xml.dom?

Comment: yes. the etree module has a HTML reader module that does a better job of handling HTML's quirks than a pure XML reader can.

Comment: Maybe I should make a new post for this, but I'm having trouble using this. I'm running parsed = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(page) in the interactive prompt and it displays the parsed output, but it doesn't seem to create an ElementTree instance as the documentation says because when I try to use the parsed object I get a variable undefined error.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, but I'm getting all kinds of errors, not well formed, invalid element, etc. Is there another option or am I going to have to result to regex?

Comment: Never go for regex for parsing XML. There is a FAQ here in SO. BTW, look for ElementTree usage examples in effbot.org. You will find sample snippets useful for your case.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take a look. I'll give you the answer on this, seems likely the best option for me, just need to get it to work. I'm having a lot of fun with this, normally I just go for an option that works knowing it's not the best. Plus it's the first thing I've written over a couple hundred lines, substantially more so when you consider the main program. I always thought programming would be a lot more difficult but once you get going everything falls into place.